# How to insert element before array?

Tags: arrays, d

O want to iterate throw array and if element of array starts with needed value, insert before it another value.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container;
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;

void main()
{
    string [] str = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"];
    foreach(s;str)
    {
        if(s.canFind("bb"))
        {
            s.array.insertBefore('x');
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error: `Error: no property 'insertBefore' for type 'dchar[]'`

Comment: insertBefore is on the library Array type, not the built in one....

Comment: does `s = "x" ~ s;` give the result you want instead of insertBefore?

Comment: gah it won't let me edit. but that should be single quotes, not double, and you gotta add `ref s` to the foreach instead of just `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing Adam's advices and localizing imports, we get a working example:

```
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    import std.algorithm;

    string [] str = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"];
    foreach(ref s;str)
    {
        if(s.canFind("bb"))
        {
            s = 'x'~s;
        }
    }
    writeln(str);
}
```

I recommend also more functional style:

```
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    import std.algorithm;

    string [] str = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"];

    writeln(str.map!(s => s.canFind("bb")?'x'~s:s));
}
```

Comment: It takes me 4s to read and completely understand the imperative code, and triple amount of time to understand (and be sure I can reason about) the declarative version.

Comment: Subjectively, this is a matter of habit. Objectively, the functional style leads to fewer errors and more efficient, especially if the code is not as trivial as this example.